# How to avoid Hugo stripping unicode characters from page's slug?

Tags: url, unicode, slug, chinese-locale, hugo

I am working with Chinese content (using UTF-8), while most of the time it generates the right url, sometimes it strips certain Chinese characters from URL.

Some examples of these characters are:

- 〇
- ○
- 〡
- 〤
- 〢
- ⺮
- 〣

When generating a page for each character, i.e.: `example.com/〇` it generates empty paths `example.com//` .

To reproduce this behaviour, add

```
slug: "foo〇○〡〤〢⺮〣21三bar"
```

in the front matter of any page Hugo will generate the following stripped path:

```
http://localhost:1313/foo21三bar/`
```

removing `〇○〡〤〢⺮〣`.

*Tested with latest Hugo release: `Hugo Static Site Generator v0.30.2 linux/amd64 BuildDate: 2017-10-19T08:34:27-03:00`*

(x-post at [discourse.hugo.com](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/url-path-misses-chinese-characters-set-in-pages-slug/9052))

Answer (score 1):

I found workaround to disable encoding/escaping of urls that contain UTF-8 (non english) chars, e.g.

```
<img {{ printf "src='%s%s'" .Site.BaseURL .imageUrl | safeHTMLAttr }} >
```